# Hyperledger Composer with HLF 1.0- how to setup credentials for network deployment?

Tags: devops, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have setup a new Hyperledger network for development, using the `configtxgen` and `cryptogen` utilities from the [getting started guide](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). This seems to generate some x.509 certificates for me for an admin user as well as a couple of standard users.

How do I then connect to this network using the `composer-cli` package (ie. `composer network deploy [...]`), as the command demands an enrolment ID and secret? It seems like I need to place one of the generated TCerts into the Composer credentials store, but I'm not sure which one or how to format the destination file. And once configured, I'm unsure how to call the `deploy` command (presumably I just omit the enrolment secret).

Comment: You are using HLF v1alpha1?

Comment: Nope, latest HLF v1 beta

Answer (score 1):

We are working on support for HLF v1-beta1 this week. We aim to deliver it for the release on Thursday 2017-06-15.

Composer 0.7.5 supports both HLF v1-alpha1 and v0.6.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to sort this out myself, but it'd be good if someone from the IBM team could confirm that this is the appropriate way of initing a config.

One issue was in my `docker-compose.yaml`, whereby I needed to set `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=bridge` since I am not using host network mode. Ensure you have this setting correct if you're running into similar issues.

In terms of the configuration I had to use `openssl` to get the public key out of the peer admin user's certificate file, and copy the private key into my `~/.hfc-key-store`:

```
PROFILE_ID="testprofile"
HOMEDIR=$HOME

# These values depend on the output of `cryptogen` and will differ
# depending on your configuration and generated files.

PEER_ORG_ID="org1.example.com"
ADMIN_CREDENTIALS_CERT_ID="eb141574a8882664511fface8bd58410ff835a93cb6ca495f45a40213977a9a1"
ADMIN_USER_ID="Admin@org1.example.com"
CRYPTO_ASSETS_DIR="./crypto-config"
SIGNCERT_FILE="${CRYPTO_ASSETS_DIR}/peerOrganizations/${PEER_ORG_ID}/users/${ADMIN_USER_ID}/msp/signcerts/${ADMIN_USER_ID}-cert.pem"
PRIVKEY_FILE="${CRYPTO_ASSETS_DIR}/peerOrganizations/${PEER_ORG_ID}/users/${ADMIN_USER_ID}/msp/keystore/${ADMIN_CREDENTIALS_CERT_ID}_sk"

# extract pubkey from signing cert
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in "$SIGNCERT_FILE" > \
  "${HOMEDIR}/.hfc-key-store/${ADMIN_CREDENTIALS_CERT_ID}-pub"

# copy private key across
cp "$PRIVKEY_FILE" \
  "${HOMEDIR}/.hfc-key-store/${ADMIN_CREDENTIALS_CERT_ID}-priv"

# generate connection profile credential file
SIGNCERT_CONTENTS=$(cat "$SIGNCERT_FILE" | sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g')
cat << EOF > ${HOMEDIR}/.hfc-key-store/PeerAdmin
{
  "name":"PeerAdmin",
  "mspid":"Org1MSP",
  "roles":null,
  "affiliation":"",
  "enrollmentSecret":"",
  "enrollment":{
    "signingIdentity":"${ADMIN_CREDENTIALS_CERT_ID}",
    "identity":{
      "id":"testIdentity",
      "certificate":"${SIGNCERT_CONTENTS}"
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

With these files in place you should be able to connect to a v1 Fabric successfully to deploy a Composer business network against it.

Comment: The command composer identity import is how you take the admin credentials of a peer and import them into your keyvalstore directory for use by composer. An example of the command can be found here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.import.html
We still need to add some more operational documentation specifically about how to set up composer to work with a pre-configured fabric setup.

Comment: Have tried this and it works perfectly, plus certainly more idiomatic to use the composer utilities. Can you post as an answer and I'll mark as accepted? cheers